# Hi, creating a maze game and seriously cannot figure out how to fix this (I'm new to AS3) :)

Tags: actionscript-3

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTest);

hitTest(evt:Event) 
 (Character.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true)
 {
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main Menu");
 }
```

Keep getting errors like

- `Level 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 8, Line 3, Column 13    1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon`.
- `Level 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 8, Line 5, Column 3 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hitTest(evt:Event) {
   if(Character.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true))
   {
     MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main Menu");
   }
}
```

Comment: also hit test return a BOOL , i think you need to test  
if(Character.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true) then do your logic :)

Comment: No, this will give you a syntax error as well. First off, what is hitTest supposed to be? The Compiler won't understand it. Define it as a function. Second, You're missing a ) in your if-conditional. i.e. `if(Character.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true))`

Comment: yes @DodgerThud , just i forget to add function , also i miss this )  in the if condition :)

Comment: Your answer has been flagged for deletion due to poor context. In your provided answer above, explain why this answer might work